# can't figure out python indentation error

Tags: python

I am writing some Airflow DAG code in Python 3.8, but there is an indentation error which I am unable to figure out. I use VScode as the IDE

Here is the code:

```
from airflow_env import DAG
from datetime import datetime

with DAG(
  dag_id='user-processing',
  schedule_interval='@daily',
  start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1)) as dag:
```

on the terminal, the error says following: `unexpected EOF while parsing`
but on the IDE I see `expected indented block pylance python`

Comment: you need to add something to the with block. even if you just add a `pass`. Python is expecting to see content there

Comment: Those two errors point to the same problem, they're just expressing it in different ways. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Have you uploaded complete code? Because i think there should be a body of `with` statement. You have instantiated a `DAG` object but you aren't using it.

Comment: thank you, it required a `task` statement to be added as part of `with/as` block. the error is gone now. I was following a tutorial for DAG where they did not talk about the task statement until few pages later. thank you all for the prompt help

Comment: Duplicate: [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](/q/45621722/4518341) There's a section that covers `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. (Sorry, I voted to close as typo before realizing there might be more to the misunderstanding.)

Answer (score 2):

```
with DAG(
  dag_id='user-processing',
  schedule_interval='@daily',
  start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1)) as dag:
```

This is the beginning of a `with`/`as` block, you can't leave it empty, at least you have to specify a `pass`:

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you, it required a task statement to be added as part of with/as block. the error is gone now. I was following a tutorial for DAG where they did not talk about the task statement until few pages later. thank you all for the prompt help

here is the rest of the code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

def helloworld():
  print("hello world")

with DAG(
  dag_id='user-processing',
  schedule_interval='@daily',
  start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1)) as dag:

  task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="hello_world",
    python_callable=helloworld
  )


task1
```